# ¿Por algun motivo no funciona mi codigo?

Tags: javascript

Pues como pone en el titulo no funciona mi código (un contador de palabaras), ósea se lo he revisado no da ningún fallo de sintaxis pero no funciona, aquí dejo mi código, aclaro que el html lo tengo por otro lado y este si funciona.

Edicion: copie el codigo de esta pagina para ver si funcionaba y aun asi nno funciona, aqui el link de la pagina: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/5nfay7d1/206/
Edicion 2 : adjunto el html.

```js
function wordCount(val) {
  var wom = val.match(/\S+/g);
  return {
    charactersNoSpaces: val.replace(/\s+/g, '').length,
    characters: val.length,
    words: wom ? wom.length : 0,
    lines: val.split(/\r*\n/).length
  };
}


var textarea = document.getElementById("text");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var v = wordCount(this.value);
  result.innerHTML = (
    "<br>Characters (no spaces):  " + v.charactersNoSpaces +
    "<br>Characters (and spaces): " + v.characters +
    "<br>Words: " + v.words +
    "<br>Lines: " + v.lines
  );
}, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Contador de palabras</h2>
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Y lo que debería hacer tu código ess....??

Comment: No pulsaste el link que deje en la pregunta?, bueno deberia contar las letras tal y como parace en el codigo de la pagina pero no funciona solo me lee el html no se porque?

Comment: Acá tratamos de publicar en la pregunta toda la información necesaria para que la comunidad pueda entender. De hecho el sitio tiene un "emulador" (no sé si esa será la descripción correcta), para que puedas incluir tu código CSS, HTML y JS si es necesario (como ahora).

Comment: No es si pulso o no, deberías especificarlo en tu pregunta, y el código es exactamente el mismo en el enlace, por lo que el error no esta ahí, deberías mostrar mas de lo que tienes.

Comment: Ahora esta con el html

Comment: A Mí me funciona perfectamente. Qué problema te da a tí?

Comment: Ya veo que aqui funciona perfectamente, mi ordenador directamente no me ejecuta el javascript solo el html, lo cual creo que es el verdadero problema, estoy utilizando Visual studio code y el navegador chrome

Comment: En ese caso el problema puede ser en como importas tu archivo js, tal vez ahí logres la solución.

Comment: @Jose Y como esyas llamando al JS entonces ??

Comment: A traves de una carpeta osea se los tengo en archivos separados esta es la ruta de mi carpeta : 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script> en src pongo la ruta de la carpeta donde esta mi archivo, he estado haciendo esto con otros ejercicios y aun asi funcionan.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo aquí, haciendo ejecutar en el snipet y funciona correctamente. Seguramente, en tu navegador se esté ejecutando el **caché de una prueba anterior**

Answer (score 0):

En donde llamas el archivo js dentro del HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

coloca la ruta completa del archivo por ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/desktop/.../javascript.js"></script>
```

Espero resuelva tu problema.